# Null input character spamming Linux tty

Tags: linux, tty, nixos

My Linux TTY is being spammed by null characters, which are preventing me from logging in. This is the case on all 6 TTY inputs. This issue seems to come and go randomly. I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting all hardware.

Any help is much appreciated :)

![image: screenshot]

Comment: Try entering this: `tput reset` followed by Control-J.

Comment: @codeforester No luck, I can't even log in on the TTY inputs (only the X login) due to the characters spamming my login

Answer (score 1):

Try to hit the capslock key and hold shift to type your login and password, after this you can try configure the system